# Evaluated but not used

Tags: go

I'm not sure what's happening here.

I'm working on Project Euler #8 and have come up with the following function to handle getting the product of 5 digits:

```
func fiveDigitProduct(n int) int {
    localMax := n + 5
    product := 1
    for n; n < localMax; n++ {
        f, _ := strconv.Atoi(input[n])
        product *= f
    }
    return product
}
```

However, I keep getting the warning "n evaluated but not used". I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: you're not using the `n`in the first part of the for loop, you have to remove it like `for ; n < localMax; n++{......`

Comment: That worked! infact, I also had to change the first line in the for loop to

`f , _ := strconv.Atoi(input[n:n+1))`

And that worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InitStmt` (initialization statement) of your [For Statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) isn't actually doing any initialization.  You're asking the compiler to evaluate `n` but not do anything with it, which is what the compiler is complaining about.  Since you don't need to initialize `n` for you loop, just do:

```
for ; n < localMax; n++ {
```

Answer (score 0):

The initialization part of a for loop as also the post part (where you increment n) needs to be a [simple statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#SimpleStmt) (and just "n" is not a statement, it'll be an expression, so what you are trying to do is syntactically incorrect). If you make the init part n = n or n := n (a new variable declaration within the scope of the for loop), it'll be a valid statement and will work. As suggested in the above posts, since you don't intend to do anything in the init part it's best to leave it out.